# NSTableView Distortion on Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I have an NSTableView which is embedded in a TabView, and i am seeing some odd drawing distortions when scrolling the table, image below. The odd thing is that i have been working on this project for over a month and this has just started happening.

I have overridden the row drawing code, which is also below, but that hasn't changed for weeks.

The only fairly significant change recently has been updating the project to XCode 5.0Dp as this application will not ship until post iOS7 release and i wanted to make sure everything was working (good thing i did as i had some code that was crashing the app in the iOS app the accompanies it).

Any help greatly appreciated!

[image: Distorted row on NSTableView]

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

// Get a new ViewCell
NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

//Identify the correct column
if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"userLogo"] )
{
    Tweet* selectedTweet;
    if(self.updatingBucket == YES){

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    //Set predicate and filter for New tweets page
    if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"new"]) {
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == NO) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and predicate for the Approved tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"approved"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == YES) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"approvedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"deleted"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tweetDeleted == YES"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"deletedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"scheduled"]){
    NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledTweet == YES"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
    [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }


    //Setup the Request
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

    //Assign the predicate to the fetch request
    NSError *error = nil;

    //Create an array from the returned objects
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    selectedTweet = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];

      } else {


          selectedTweet = [self.onScreenTweets objectAtIndex:row];

      }


    cellView.imageView.image = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("getAsynchronIconsGDQueue", NULL),
                   ^{
                       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:selectedTweet.avatarUrl];
                       NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
                       cellView.imageView.image = image;
                   });

    //[cellView setWantsLayer:YES];
    return cellView;

}
```

**EDIT 1**

Here is the drawing code for the table rows:

```
//Load the image into the table

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

// Get a new ViewCell
NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

if(tableView == self.tweetTableView){

//Identify the correct column
if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"userLogo"] )
{
    Tweet* selectedTweet;
    if(self.updatingBucket == YES || self.facebookFetching == YES){

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    //Set predicate and filter for New tweets page
    if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"new"]) {
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == NO) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and predicate for the Approved tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"approved"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == YES) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"approvedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"deleted"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tweetDeleted == YES"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"deletedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"scheduled"]){
    NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledTweet == YES"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
    [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }


    //Setup the Request
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

    //Assign the predicate to the fetch request
    NSError *error = nil;

    //Create an array from the returned objects
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    selectedTweet = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];

      } else {


          selectedTweet = [self.onScreenTweets objectAtIndex:row];

      }


    cellView.imageView.image = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("getAsynchronIconsGDQueue", NULL),
                   ^{
                       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:selectedTweet.avatarUrl];
                       NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
                       cellView.imageView.image = image;
                   });


    //[cellView setWantsLayer:YES];
    return cellView;

} if([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondButtons"]){
    Tweet* selectedTweet;

    if(self.updatingBucket == YES){

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


        //Set predicate and filter for New tweets page
        if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"new"]) {
            NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == NO) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:NO];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
            [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
            [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

            //Set filter and predicate for the Approved tweets page
        } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"approved"]){
            NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == YES) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"approvedDate" ascending:NO];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
            [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
            [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

            //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
        } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"deleted"]){
            NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tweetDeleted == YES"];
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"deletedDate" ascending:NO];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
            [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
            [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

            //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
        } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"scheduled"]){
            NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledTweet == YES"];
            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:NO];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
            [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
            [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        }


        //Setup the Request
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

        //Assign the predicate to the fetch request
        NSError *error = nil;

        //Create an array from the returned objects
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        selectedTweet = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];

    } else {


        selectedTweet = [self.onScreenTweets objectAtIndex:row];

    }

    if(selectedTweet.imageURL){

        //NSTableCellView *buttonCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"secondButtons" owner:self];
        //[buttonCell setHidden:NO];
        //return buttonCell;

    } else {

        //NSTableCellView *buttonCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"secondButtons" owner:self];
        //[buttonCell setHidden:YES];
        //return buttonCell;

    }


}

} else{
    NSTableCellView *cellView2 = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    return cellView2;

}
//[cellView setWantsLayer:YES];
return cellView;
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I have the same problem. Odd that if I only fill the background of the cell everything's fine.

Comment: No, but it has somehow magically gone away, i think this has to be an OSX update created issue, and maybe a subsequent update fixed it. Do let me know if you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I'll try it out in my Mavericks VM once I have some time. If it's fixed there it's definitively an OS X thing. Will let you know if I should find out something.

Comment: Okay, I was able to fix the bug in my case. It was in my custom drawing code. Where do you do your drawing operations? I guess in drawRect. If so what NSRect do you use? Best would probably be if you post your drawing code.

Comment: I have added the row drawing code above, any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Do you override `heightForRowAtIndexPath` with the incorrect values ?

Comment: Do you set the background color in XIB? My problem was that in my NSTableViewCell Subclass I overwrite drawRect to draw my cell. The mistake I made is to use the dirtyRect attribute of drawRect instead of self.bounds. DirtyRect is only the rect which newly appeared on screen.

Comment: My heigh for row override looks like this: - (CGFloat) tableView: (NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow: (NSInteger) row;{
    return 56;
}